# How to use setText() function on List<String>

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I am creating the app where the players put their names into a program, the program sends their names to the next activity in a String array, and the next program puts the array into a list an then shuffles it. For some reason, everytime I try to use the.setText function, the app gets a nullpointerexception error. I have tested the list with a toast to verify that it is not null, which it is not. Any suggestions?

```
endInstructions = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonEndInstructions);

    player = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewPlayerName);

    endInstructions.setOnClickListener(this);

    Bundle ext = getIntent().getExtras();
    int numberOfPlayers= ext.getInt("numberofplayers");
    String[] sarray = ext.getStringArray("namearray");

    names = Arrays.asList(sarray);
    Collections.shuffle(names);

    Toast.makeText(this, names.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //player.setText(names.get(0));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your `player` is not null ?

Comment: please see the log cat line no where exception is and see that line in code .......

Comment: is it working fine after commenting //player.setText(names.get(0)) ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not a million solutions...

Player is null, you can check that by testing:

```
 Toast.makeText(this, player, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

What does that mean? Probably that your current layout does not contains a textview called "textViewPlayerName"

Please double check your xml layout or be sure that you used setContentView before ;-)

Edit: as endInstructions is not null regarding your code, you corretly used setContentView before...

Comment: Ok, i fixed it. It was caused because I tried to initialize the variable before I called setContentView with the layout containing the text view. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the GUI object player is null. You can verify this if you place a try/catch block, and read the error message after causing the exception.

I suspect the GUI object ID R.id.**textViewPlayerName** does not exist or not the class type **TextView**. And thus player is null. For example, maybe the object type is *TextField* instead, or any other valid types in the Android framework.

Good luck and let us know of your progress.